# Django Create Comment View pass Subject pk

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm learning Django and have been beating my head against a wall trying to make a comment form work correctly. Basically what I'm building is a recipe app. This is just practice but the idea would be that someone posts a recipe and other people can comment on it. I have it basically working but I cannot work out how to have the redirect go back to the recipe detail view after the comment has been submitted.

If I hard code in the pk it works, I just need to get a hold of that pk!

Here is my stuff:

```
Portion of Recipes views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, View
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

#from comments.models import Comment
from .models import Recipe
from comments.models import Comment

from .forms import RecipeCreateForm
from comments.forms import CommentFormTrial
from comments.views import CommentCreateView

class PersonalRecipeListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Recipe.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class RecipeDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = RecipeContent.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        view = CommentCreateView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)


class RecipeContent(DetailView):
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipes/recipe_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'recipe_data'   


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecipeContent, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print('-------------------')
        print(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        qs= Comment.objects.filter(recipe=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        context['comments'] = qs

        comment_form = CommentFormTrial
        context['comment_form'] = comment_form

        return context
```

And my comments view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Comment
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .forms import CommentFormTrial


# Create your views here.
class CommentListView(ListView):
    model = Comment
    context_object_name = 'comments'
    template_name='comments/testcomment.html'


class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentFormTrial

    success_url = reverse_lazy('recipes:recipe-detail', kwargs = {'pk':10})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(CommentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You can see I have hard coded in '10' for the PK in the success_url. With this done it works but obviously only redirects to that one recipe.

At the moment I'm selecting the recipe I want to comment on from a drop down on the comment modal which isn't ideal either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a form to your `RecipeContent` view for posting the comment. Create the form and add it to the context. Include the `pk` as a hidden field in your template so it gets posted and is directly accessible by the `CommentCreateView`. That way the user doesn't have to use your pull-down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments need to have a reference to the Recipe they're linked to. I'm assuming your `Comment` model has a `ForeignKey` to `Recipe`?

So your `CommentCreateView` needs to receive an extra attribute, which is the `pk` to the `Recipe`. It looks like your `kwargs` already has that key, which is passed to your `CommentCreateView`. So in your `CommentView`, you just need to override:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    return recipe.get_absolute_url()
```

and don't define the `success_url` at the class level.

Comment: Thank you so much Dirk I really appreciate the help. Its working now. Cheers!